# Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in JS isomorphic app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am building a Typescript package which should be running on both front end and back end. I am using this package to recognise if environment is browser or node:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-or-node
The entry point is a single index.js file

I can build and publish the application with no issue however when I import it and try to run it in the browser I get the error message 
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs'`

This seems to come from the fact that I am importing fs which is a node method and the browser doesn't know what to do.

What is the best practices in this case to avoid this issue? If I don't import that module the library works just fine.

My package.json:

```
"license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "test": "mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.spec.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.7",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.6",
    "@types/sinon": "^7.0.11",
    "@types/sinon-chai": "^3.2.2",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.1.4",
    "sinon": "^7.3.2",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "browser-or-node": "^1.2.1",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0"
  }
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": [ "es2015" ]
  },
  "exclude":[
    "node_modules",
    "./dist",
    "./**/*.spec.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

The function that causes the issue:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

export function saveTokensNode(data: any, path: string) {
    try {
        fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(data))
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Where I am using it:

```
setCredentials(tokens) {
    if (isBrowser) {
        saveTokensStorage(tokens)
    }

    if (isNode) {
        saveTokensNode(tokens, 'temp/tokensToStore.json')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is that you can use the ["browser" package.json field](https://github.com/defunctzombie/package-browser-field-spec#ignore-a-module) to exclude a module from browser bundles. It's supported by all major bundlers.

```
{
  "browser": {
    "fs": false
  }
}
```

Then, in browserify, you'll get an empty object when you import `fs`. I'm not sure what other bundlers do, though!

---

But you can actually do this slightly differently and avoid the need for a browser-or-node package. You could have two files for the node and browser implementations of token storage. For example,

```
// token-storage.js
import * as fs from "fs"
export function saveTokens() { /* Node implementation */ }

// token-storage.browser.js
export function saveTokens() { /* localStorage implementation */ }
```

You can switch between them, again using the "browser" field.

```
{
  "browser": {
    "./path/to/token-storage.js": "./path/to/token-storage.browser.js"
  }
}
```

Then, in your module, you can do:

```
import { saveTokens } from "./token-storage.js"
function setCredentials (tokens) {
  saveTokens(tokens, 'temp/tokensToStore.json')
}
```

The browser implementation could ignore the file path, or use it as a localStorage key name. It keeps the node/browser decision localised to the token-storage file and you don't have to think about it when you use it anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks how does it work with Typescript? Because I guess on .  {
  "browser": {
    "./path/to/token-storage.js": "./path/to/token-storage.browser.js"
  }
}       I can not pass a .ts file right?

Comment: I have tried the above but it does not seems to be working for me..Is the idea to have two different files in the output? e.g. "index.js" and "bundle.js"? When I publish the library how would the client that is consuming know which one to use